# Cargar datos en tabla desde file

Tags: javascript

Buen día, tengo un problema con este programa, intento colocar los datos leídos de un "file" en una tabla, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, los datos que se leen son en pares de 2, (Archivo hex) y esos datos deben escribirse en la tabla ordenadamente hasta la fila 15 y luego crear otra fila.

Por ahora solo logro colocar los datos en un cuadro de texto, pero no he conseguido hacerlo en la tabla. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como realizar esto?

Adjunto el código completo mas abajo, puse un ejemplo de la tabla
Adjunto enlace de un archivo de ejemplo HEX
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zvX4_MvpzEHN-2LraU_p6zNtXpsrdRQm/view?usp=sharing

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>codemax</title>
  <!--titulo de pagina-->

  <link href="estilos/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <input type="file" id="inp">
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="Compilar">COMPILAR</button>
    <section>
      <textarea id="respuesta" contentEditable="true">HEX</textarea>
    </section>
    <script>
      function hexDump(file) {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
          if (!(file instanceof Blob)) {
            rej('Elige Un Archivo');
          }
          const fr = new FileReader();
          fr.onload = e => {
            res(hex(fr.result));
          };
          fr.onerror = e => rej('No se pudo leer');
          fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });

        function hex(buffer) {
          const hexCodes = [];
          const view = new DataView(buffer);
          for (let i = 0; i < view.byteLength; i += 4) {

            let value = view.getUint32(i);
            let stringValue = value.toString(16);
            let padding = '00000000';
            let paddedValue = (padding + stringValue).slice(-padding.length).toUpperCase();
            hexCodes.push(paddedValue.slice(0, 4),
              paddedValue.slice(4, 8)
              /*,
              paddedValue.slice(8, 12),
              paddedValue.slice(12, 16)*/
            );
          }

          hexCodes.join(' ');

          let finalx = [];
          for (let i = 1; i < hexCodes.length + 1; ++i) {
            finalx += hexCodes[i - 1];
          }

          return finalx;
        }

      }

      var respuesta = document.querySelector("#respuesta");
      var hexSinFormato;


      inp.onchange = e => {
        alert("Analizando...");
        hexDump(inp.files[0]).then(hex => {
            hexSinFormato = hex;
            respuesta.value = Format(hex, 2, " ", 32);
            /* respuesta2.value=Format(HexToAscii(hexSinFormato), 2, "   ", 16)*/

          })
          .catch(e => alert(e));
      }

      function Format(texto, padding, separador, paddingSalto) {
        let str = "";
        for (let j = 1; j < texto.length + 1; ++j) {
          str += texto[j - 1];
          if (j % padding == 0) {
            str += separador;
          }
          if (j >= paddingSalto) {
            if (j % paddingSalto == 0) {
              str += "\n"; /* espacio entre el tecto*/
            }
          }
        }
        return str;
      }



      /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    </script>

    <section>
      <table id="hextable">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="offsetcount">&nbsp;</td>
            <th>00</th>
            <th>01</th>
            <th>02</th>
            <th>03</th>
            <th>04</th>
            <th>05</th>
            <th>06</th>
            <th>07</th>
            <th>08</th>
            <th>09</th>
            <th>0A</th>
            <th>0B</th>
            <th>0C</th>
            <th>0D</th>
            <th>0E</th>
            <th>0F</th>
          </tr>
          <td class="offsetcount">000000</td>
          <td id="h0" onmouseover="ViewMOver(this);" onmouseout="ViewMOut(this);" class="">
            <div class=""></div>
          </td>
      </table>
      </table>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

modifique un poco la tabla para que entraran 2 digitos por cuadro, ahora no se como hacer que se genere una fila nueva pero con un numero
ejemplo - se llena la primera fila y crea la siguiente con el nombre "0010"la otra  "0020" y asi hasta que se cargen todos los datos

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>codemax</title>
  <!--titulo de pagina-->

  <link href="estilos/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <input type="file" id="inp">
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="Compilar">COMPILAR</button>
    <section>
      <textarea id="respuesta" contentEditable="true">HEX</textarea>
    </section>
    <script>
      function hexDump(file) {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
          if (!(file instanceof Blob)) {
            rej('Elige Un Archivo');
          }
          const fr = new FileReader();
          fr.onload = e => {
            res(hex(fr.result));
          };
          fr.onerror = e => rej('No se pudo leer');
          fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });

        function hex(buffer) {
          const hexCodes = [];
          const view = new DataView(buffer);
          for (let i = 0; i < view.byteLength; i += 4) {

            let value = view.getUint32(i);
            let stringValue = value.toString(16);
            let padding = '00000000';
            let paddedValue = (padding + stringValue).slice(-padding.length).toUpperCase();
            hexCodes.push(paddedValue.slice(0, 4),
              paddedValue.slice(4, 8)
              /*,
              paddedValue.slice(8, 12),
              paddedValue.slice(12, 16)*/
            );
          }

          hexCodes.join(' ');

          let finalx = [];
          for (let i = 1; i < hexCodes.length + 1; ++i) {
            finalx += hexCodes[i - 1];
          }

          return finalx;
        }

      }

      var respuesta = document.querySelector("#respuesta");
      var hexSinFormato;


      inp.onchange = e => {
        alert("Analizando...");
        hexDump(inp.files[0]).then(hex => {
            hexSinFormato = hex;
            $('#hextable').html(formathex(hex,2, " ", 32));
            respuesta.value = Format(hex, 2, " ", 32);
            /* respuesta2.value=Format(HexToAscii(hexSinFormato), 2, "   ", 16)*/

          })
          .catch(e => alert(e));
      }

      function formathex(text){
        content=`<table><tr>
               <td>  </td>
            <th>00</th> <td>  </td>
            <th>01</th> <td>  </td>
            <th>02</th><td>    </td>
            <th>03</th><td>   </td>
            <th>04</th><td>   </td>
            <th>05</th> <td>  </td>
            <th>06</th> <td>  </td>
            <th>07</th> <td>  </td>
            <th>08</th> <td>  </td>
            <th>09</th> <td>  </td>
            <th>0A</th> <td>  </td>
            <th>0B</th> <td>  </td>
            <th>0C</th> <td>  </td>
            <th>0D</th> <td>  </td>
            <th>0E</th> <td>  </td> 
            <th>0F</th> <td>  </td>
         
          </tr>
          <tr>`
            
        for (let j = 0; j < text.length; ++j) {
          if(j%32===0){
            content+="<tr>"
            
          }
          content+="<td>"
            content+=text[j]
          content+="</td>"
          
          
        }
        content+="</table>"
        return content;
      }

      function Format(texto, padding, separador, paddingSalto) {
        let str = "";
        for (let j = 1; j < texto.length + 1; ++j) {
          str += texto[j - 1];
          if (j % padding == 0) {
            str += separador;
          }
          if (j >= paddingSalto) {
            if (j % paddingSalto == 0) {
              str += "\n"; /* espacio entre el tecto*/
            }
          }
        }
        return str;
      }



      /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    </script>

    <section>
      <table id="hextable">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="table">&nbsp;</td>
            <th>00</th>
            <th>01</th>
            <th>02</th>
            <th>03</th>
            <th>04</th>
            <th>05</th>
            <th>06</th>
            <th>07</th>
            <th>08</th>
            <th>09</th>
            <th>0A</th>
            <th>0B</th>
            <th>0C</th>
            <th>0D</th>
            <th>0E</th>
            <th>0F</th>
          </tr>
          <td class="offsetcount">000000</td>
          
      </table>
      </table>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: agrega un ejemplo del archivo que quieres agregar, entiendo que es de tipo biario por lo que pusiste

Comment: Hola, agrego el enlace, con un ejemplo de un archivo hex
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zvX4_MvpzEHN-2LraU_p6zNtXpsrdRQm/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a relizar el ejemplo con [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), ya que es excelente manipulando el dom y ahorrará mucho código, pero por supuesto que puedes realizarlo con js vainilla.

La lógica es la siguiente:

Vas al elemento que contiene la tabla
allí toca reemplazar todo el contenido interno
Primero agregas el encabezado, para que se vea igual
luego como tienes 16 columnas cada vez que tu columna sea múltiplo de 16 vas a agregar una nueva fila mediante la etiqueta `tr`.
Cada texto para que sea una celda deberá encerrarse en etiquetas `td`

```js
function hexDump(file) {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
          if (!(file instanceof Blob)) {
            rej('Elige Un Archivo');
          }
          const fr = new FileReader();
          fr.onload = e => {
            res(hex(fr.result));
          };
          fr.onerror = e => rej('No se pudo leer');
          fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });

        function hex(buffer) {
          const hexCodes = [];
          const view = new DataView(buffer);
          for (let i = 0; i < view.byteLength; i += 4) {

            let value = view.getUint32(i);
            let stringValue = value.toString(16);
            let padding = '00000000';
            let paddedValue = (padding + stringValue).slice(-padding.length).toUpperCase();
            hexCodes.push(paddedValue.slice(0, 4),
              paddedValue.slice(4, 8)
              /*,
              paddedValue.slice(8, 12),
              paddedValue.slice(12, 16)*/
            );
          }

          hexCodes.join(' ');

          let finalx = [];
          for (let i = 1; i < hexCodes.length + 1; ++i) {
            finalx += hexCodes[i - 1];
          }

          return finalx;
        }

      }

      var respuesta = document.querySelector("#respuesta");
      var hexSinFormato;


      inp.onchange = e => {
        alert("Analizando...");
        hexDump(inp.files[0]).then(hex => {
            hexSinFormato = hex;
            $('#hextable').html(formatHtml(hex));
            respuesta.value = Format(hex, 2, " ", 32);
            /* respuesta2.value=Format(HexToAscii(hexSinFormato), 2, "   ", 16)*/

          })
          .catch(e => alert(e));
      }
      
      function formatHtml(text){
        content=`<table><tr>
            <th>00</th>
            <th>01</th>
            <th>02</th>
            <th>03</th>
            <th>04</th>
            <th>05</th>
            <th>06</th>
            <th>07</th>
            <th>08</th>
            <th>09</th>
            <th>0A</th>
            <th>0B</th>
            <th>0C</th>
            <th>0D</th>
            <th>0E</th>
            <th>0F</th>
          </tr><tr>`
        for (let j = 0; j < text.length; ++j) {
          if(j%16===0){
            content+="<tr>"
          }
          content+="<td>"
            content+=text[j]
          content+="</td>"
          
          
        }
        content+="</table>"
        return content;
      }

      function Format(texto, padding, separador, paddingSalto) {
        let str = "";
        for (let j = 1; j < texto.length + 1; ++j) {
          str += texto[j - 1];
          if (j % padding == 0) {
            str += separador;
          }
          if (j >= paddingSalto) {
            if (j % paddingSalto == 0) {
              str += "\n"; /* espacio entre el tecto*/
            }
          }
        }
        return str;
      }



      /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>codemax</title>
  <!--titulo de pagina-->

  <link href="estilos/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <input type="file" id="inp">
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="Compilar">COMPILAR</button>
    <section>
      <textarea id="respuesta" contentEditable="true">HEX</textarea>
    </section>
    <section>
      <table id="hextable">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>00</th>
            <th>01</th>
            <th>02</th>
            <th>03</th>
            <th>04</th>
            <th>05</th>
            <th>06</th>
            <th>07</th>
            <th>08</th>
            <th>09</th>
            <th>0A</th>
            <th>0B</th>
            <th>0C</th>
            <th>0D</th>
            <th>0E</th>
            <th>0F</th>
          </tr>
          <td class="offsetcount">000000</td>
          <td id="h0" class="">
            <div class=""></div>
          </td>
      </table>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```